# The declared package does not match the expected package. (android.support.v7.appcompat)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The declared package `android.support.v7.appcompat` does not match the expected package `gen.android.support.v7.appcompat`

I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Perhaps if it read as, 'the declared package "android.support.v7.appcompat" does not match the expected package "gen.android.support.v7.appcompat based on where it is in its Source Folder'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `appcompat v7` as a project in Eclipse, then add it to the project as a **library**, from the **Android option** not from the Java Build Path, like this:

[image]

Make sure the "is Library" is checked in the appcompat_v7 project if you can't add it form the "Add" button.

Hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You might have the project itself set as a Source Folder rather than the "gen" folder. Open the Properties dialog for the project and fix the Java Build Path.

Comment: What would be the fix once im in the Java Build Path? @nitind